# Asserting several variables as same type

Tags: python, assertion, isinstance

**The problem:** I have a function that takes in parameters `n` and `base`, and I would like to assure that both of these parameters are in fact integers. So far I've done the following:

```
#  Conditions in which the function makes sense.
assert isinstance(n, (int)), 'n must be an integer. n: {0}'.format(n)
assert isinstance(base, (int)), 'base must be an integer. base: {0}'.format(base)
assert not isinstance(n, bool)
```

**The question:** This seems tedious, I would like to somehow do something similar to `assert isinstance((n, base), (int, int)), 'n and base must be integers. n: {0}, base: {1}'.format(n, base)`. But this gives me an AssertionError at unexpected times (`n` and `base` are both int). Perhaps tuples can't be used? Is there an analogous approach that do work?

Edit: I guess an ideal handling would be to list every parameter that should be of type t, and if one or more fails, print out only the ones failing.

For completeness, under follows the entire code. I don't think it will be useful, but I might be mistaken. It is not part of anything, I was just goofing around with optional arguments after looking at another question in here.

```
def pascal(n, base=1):
    """Makes a dictionary where the keys are row-indexes in a pascal-trangle
    of size n, and the values are the rows as a list. E.g. pascal(3) should
    return {1 : [1], 2: [1,1], 3: [1,2,1]}.

    pascal(0) should returns an empty dictionary.

    Optional argument 'base=': set an integer as a new base. E.g.
    pascal(3, base=2) should return {1: [2], 2: [2, 2], 3: [2, 4, 2]}"""

    #  Conditions in which the function makes sense.
    #  assert isinstance((n, base), (int, int)), 'n and base must be integers. n: {0}, base: {1}'.format(n, base)
    assert isinstance(n, (int)), 'n must be an integer. n: {0}'.format(n)
    assert isinstance(base, (int)), 'base must be an integer. base: {0}'.format(base)
    assert not isinstance(n, bool)

    if not n:
        return {}
    if n == 1:
        return {1: [base]} #  The basic case.
    else:
        bottom_row = list()
        prev_p = pascal(n-1, base) #  Only do one recursive call!
        for i in range(0, n):
            if i == 0:
                bottom_row.append(prev_p[n-1][i])
            elif i == n-1:
                bottom_row.append(prev_p[n-1][i-1])
            else:
                bottom_row.append(prev_p[n-1][i-1]+prev_p[n-1][i])
        bottom_row = {n: bottom_row}
        pascal_dict = prev_p
        pascal_dict.update(bottom_row)
        return pascal_dict
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a vectorized `isinstance`.

```
assert isinstance((n, base), (int, int))
```

Should be

```
assert isinstance(n, int) and isinstance(base, int)
```

If you have a larger quantity of variables ...

```
for var in [n, base, count, blah, foo, bar]:
    assert isinstance(var, int)
```

If you don't need individual servicing on them:

```
assert(all(isinstance(var, int) for var in list))
```

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps there's a more simplified way to do this? For a few variables it works fine, but I imagine that you could have lots of them. Guess it could be handled in a for-loop.

On another note, the bool-assertion is not redundant. Without it pascal(True) would return {1: [1]}, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're wrong, the check for `bool` is not redundant because `bool` is a subclass of `int`. Now whether it's worth checking for is debatable, since it really is an `int` it won't break anything.

Comment: While you're at it, you have a lot of redundant parentheses.

Comment: @MarkRansom I know, I'm sorry. I come from Lisp and Java and Haskell, just now learning Python.

Comment: @RoyM The check for `bool` isn't necessary, since they are `int`s would behave as expected. `pascal(True)` _would_ return `{1: [1]}`, and that _does_ make sense. It's what you would expect from `pascal(1)`.

Comment: @nog642 I guess you're right. Personally I just find it unpleasing, but then again it doesn't interfere or do anything bad, so there's no real reason to do that functionality-reduction.